# Perform PCA Transformation with N_components = Original_num_of_Dimensions

Tags: pca

I'm currently studying the Principal Component analysis. I got a rough idea on how it works and I was wondering if applying PCA on a Dataset of n Dimensions make sense if you set the number of principal components = n.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you did center the data in the first step (which is required), then PCA with all dimensions is "only" a rotation of the dataset without loss of Information.

After the rotation (if you sort the eigenvectors descending regarding their Eigenvalues) the first Dimension is the one with the highest variance of data.

If it does make sense depends on what you expect.

An example could be the picture from the german Wikipedia [site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptkomponentenanalyse) for PCA

[image]